# Why aren’t my Reminders repeating?

Tags: ios, reminders

I have an iPad Pro with iOS 13.3. I have set a number of Reminders with repeats, but none of them are repeating. They don’t show up on the Lock screen as notifications, and if I look inside the app under the “Today” or “Scheduled” panels, they are only scheduled for their original days. Even though they say “Repeat daily” on them, they are not actually moving up in the queue.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that in the new version of the app, iOS 13, you have to actually “complete” a to do, by clicking on the complete circle, before it will repeat.